# RewriteRule to redirect with url that got parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to use RewriteRule inorder to redirect form x page to y page.
x page got two parameters > products.php?product=$1&page=$2 (myweb.com/products.php?prod...)
y should be $1/$2/ (myweb.com/$1/$2/)

I tried this one >

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^products.php?product=(.*) $1/ [R=301,L]
```

just for testing, and some similiar codes like > `/$1/` instead `$1/`, only `$1`
I tried to use RewriteCond with query_string but nothing worked....

ofc that there's continue to the htaccess >

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

and some more rules which are not relevant (I think)

Can you help me please?

Thanks.

EDIT:

After some massive searches I found the answer!
this is the answer:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^test.php$ %1/? [R=301,L]
```

now for the explanation:
first of all, added rewritecondition that will match the query string.
second I remove the query string from the rewrite rule and the $ = the continue (the query string). I also needed to add ? (question mark) at the second part of the rewriterule > `%1/?` the question mark mean that I dont want to preserve the query string in the new url.

Comment: 'RewriteRule` has nothing to do with PHP.  You may want to remove that 'php' tag.

Comment: Removed, though I think it is related to php because 95% of the people who use php also use the htacces (rewriterules).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of your rule should contain a regular expression against which the server can compare the request.  For instance:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?  index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

That would take http://somedomain.fake/somepage/ and redirect it to http://somedomain.fake/index.php?page=somepage.  The first part of the rule matches, the second part handles.  My rule there, "([^/]+)", is regular expression that will match anything.  If you want to narrow the way your rule works, you can customize the regular expression to include or exclude certain string parts.

I suggest you consider adding the follow conditions above your rule.  They ensure that if the file or directory that matches the rule actually exists, the server does not override the actual files with the rewrite.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

.htaccess and mod_rewrite is voodoo, to use an old quote.  Be sure you research thoroughly before implementing this kind of thing on a live site.

--------------------- Edit:

Updated after discussion:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^products\.php$ %1.php [L]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^products\.php$ %1/ [L]
```

Comment: I dont want to redirect to php page. I want to redirect page that has its own rewrite rule (forexample I got the following rule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]. so if I go to ^products.php?product=$1 it will redirect me to $1/ which has his rule...

Comment: Then, as I mentioned, you'd want to craft your regular expression as such: RewriteRule ^products.php?product=([^/]+)?  $1/ [L].  The first part of the rule is always some kind of regular expression or string (no variables), the second part is where you use the variables gathered by the regular expression used in the first.

Comment: tried this one > RewriteRule ^products.php?product=([^/]+)? www.youtube.com [R=301,L] and went to myweb.com/products.php?product=test and it didnt redirect me to youtube. still not working...

Comment: Gah.  See, voodo.  Please see the answer, I have added an updated (and confirmed) rule.

Comment: My website is live so I cannot put the same rule. this is the what I added/changed in the htaccess 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=([^/]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^test\.php$ %1.php [R=301,L]
went to myweb.com/test.php?product=something and it redirected me to myweb.com/something.php?product=somehthing which is wrong.... should redirect me to myweb.com/something/

Comment: Ron, you are giving me conflicting details here (or I am misunderstanding) about where you want the redirect to go.  Is it myweb.com/something/ or myweb.com/something.php?  Also, I tested the rule by itself and it performs exactly as intended.  Right now, it is redirecting to myweb.com/something.php.  If you want it to go to myweb.com/something, change the second half of the rule there to read "%1/" instead of "%1.php.

Comment: @Chris, leave my last comment. ur rule is working but it does something that it shouldnt.. as I said if I go to myweb.com/products.php?product=test it should redirect to myweb.com/test/ but in reality it redirect to myweb.com/test/?product=test .... if you want to see ur self what I am talking about go to www.codecaged.com/test.php?product=schedule-manager and look at the address bar.