# Rewritten URL shows 404 errors

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have re-written my URL from `website.com?id=1` to `website.com/1` and I'm getting 404 errors when trying to access the page and cannot think of a solution to this. I'm currently developing a link shortener. This is required so users will be able to access their shorted links.

This is my current .htaccessfile

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /(index\.php)?\?id=([0-9]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%3?%4 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I cannot figure out whether this has something to do with the .htaccess file or if I need to add something else to my php code.

Would someone have some sort of idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly rewrite back to `index.php` in your second rule. By the time rewrite rules are processed the `DirectoryIndex` directive has already been processed (or may never be processed at all - it depends a little on your virtual host configuration and in what scope the `DirectoryIndex` directive was declared).

The end result of this is that you need to explicitly rewrite the request to the script that you want to handle the request, you can't just rewrite it to the root of a directory. Try changing your second rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

On a personal note, it's interesting to see someone else use the `%{THE_REQUEST}` approach to this problem, this is an idea that I myself only recently came up with, although presumably I am not the first to do so. For the benefit of future visitors, here is a [related post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25205/automatically-redirect-index-php-to-directory-or-root-with-htaccess) that explains why this requirement would come about and the thinking behind it.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck :/ I'm pretty sure this is configured as told but: http://pastebin.com/gR7VFeNg and if you are interested in having a look at the error itself. http://oli.pw?id=1. It should echo something like 'URL is set' but instead it takes me to a blank 404.

Comment: @OliverK I take it these rules are in a .htaccess in the root directory, and not in httpd.conf or a sub-directory?

Comment: Oh wow.. I had a complete blonde moment. I had the .htaccess in another file. The root but not the folder in-which this domain was held. My bad. I'll give you credit for this one, it is very informative. Thanks a-lot!

Comment: @OliverK No worries. FWIW I would probably do something more like [this](http://pastebin.com/mJPCNDTe) (untested) in the first cond/rule - it's a little more forgiving of some minor HTTP violations that Apache will probably forgive and it would no longer rely on the `id` parameter appearing first in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have written wrong rewrite rules.

They must be something like this:

for `example.com/website.php?id=x`..

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^/]+)$
  RewriteRule ^website\.php$ %1/ [L]
```

as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4951918/2274209

Hope this will solve your query.

Comment: Where did `product` come from?

Comment: I have already provided the reference where did the product came from, and edited my answer too