# RewriteRule issue - modular php Bad Request

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I'm ultimately looking to do is do /about instead of /main.php?p=about. I've seen a few posts ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951898/rewriterule-to-redirect-with-url-that-got-parameters)!) but none seem to work from me.

Firstly, I was putting the ReWrite rules in httpd.conf..is this correct?
Lots of places mention .htaccess but I didn't have that file in any directory that seems important (the only references are in phpMyAdmin). I copied the file from phpMyAdmin into htdocs and then replaced the text with a simple rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule home main.php [L]
```

However localhost/home reported a Bad Request.

So firstly which file should I use & if .htaccess where should I put the file & do I have to reference it in any other files? Secondly, is the following likely to work for my desired approach?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?  main.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Thanks for any clarity & help.
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have conditions (`RewriteCond`) after `RewriteRule`. It should be other way round.

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /main.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^home/?$ main.php [L,NC]
```

#### Suggested Read: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled but where is .htaccess enabled through httpd.conf? I have 2 mentions of it in comments: <Files ".ht*">Require all denied</Files> is the first and then the other is: AllowOverride All

Comment: It's working now. It must have just been the missing .htaccesss file. Thanks so much :) I can't accept your answer for another 10 mins

Comment: You actually had conditions (`RewriteCond`) after `RewriteRule`. It should be other way round.