# .htaccess URL Redirectin

Tags: .htaccess, url

how to redirect url using ,htaccess file?

```
www.volume.pk/about?c=145
```

to

```
www.volume.pk/home/about/145
```

I have tried

```
Redirectmatch 301 ^/about.php?c=145$ http://volume.pk/home/about/145
```

and

```
Redirectmatch 301 /about.php?c=145 http://volume.pk/home/about/145
```

but it gives to many redirects error

Comment: Many many tutorials on the web... [Like this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951898/rewriterule-to-redirect-with-url-that-got-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

QueryString is not part of match in RedirectMatch directive, you need to match against %{QUERY_STRING} variable using a RewriteCond.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=145$
RewriteRule ^about/?$ /home/about/145? [L,R]
```

The Rule will redirect **/about/** to **/home/about/145** if the query string is **?c=145** (/about/?c=145)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home/about/([^/]*)$ /about?c=$1 [L]
```

It will leave you with the URL: `www.volume.pk/home/about/145`. Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.